# How to access files in my hosting server using silverlight app

Tags: silverlight-4.0, filesystems

I'm developing a silverlight app which needs to create some files in the hosting server whenever there is an updation in the data. I googled for this scenario but as of now no luck...Pls advice on this approach.

Thanks,

Magz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a web service that to serve as a bridge between the silverlight app and the hosting server.